# Trying to get pricing from quantity breakdown

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a pricing table and a line items order table. The pricing table has prices per qty meaning one part will have multiple price points depending on qty ordered

1. 1---------95.00
2. 13--------85.00
3. 3000------65.00

My orders table has the total qty ordered. I am trying to figure out the # of orders at each qty point. One of the things giving me problems is that each part will have a different pricing breakdown. Would I use a group by - having? I don't think that will work very well. Is there another function that I should be looking into? I can get each item and it's order and how much was paid but what's the best way to do a count of orders by qty breakdown? Sorry if this is poorly explained :)

Pricing table example

```
Item #-------QTY-------Price
525001-------1-------59.00
525001-------8-------55.00
525001-------13------45.00
```

Order Table

```
Order #-------item#-------item_qty------unit_cost
51788---------525001------9-------------55.00
51789---------525001------2-------------59.00
51790---------525001------50000---------45.00
```

This is just the qty breakdown for this product, other products have different breakpoints.

Comment: can you add tables structure, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @prices table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    item int,
    Qty int,
    Price float
)

declare @orders table
(
    id int identity(1000,1),
    item int,
    item_qty int
)

insert into @prices (item, Qty, Price)
values 
(525001,1, 59),
(525001,8, 55),
(525001,13, 45)

insert into @orders (item, item_qty)
values
(525001,9),
(525001,2),
(525001,50000)
```

---

```
select Id, max(Price) as retail_price, sum(Item_qty) as items_sold, count(IdOrder) as orders_count
 from
(
    select 
        o.item_qty,
        o.Id as idOrder,
        p.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by o.Item, o.Id order by p.Qty desc) as num
    from @orders o
    join @prices p on p.Item = o.Item and p.Qty <= o.item_qty   
) T
where t.num = 1
group by id, item

/* 
Id  retail_price    items_sold  orders_count
1   59              2           1
2   55              9           1
3   45              50000       1
*/
```

Comment: would i use select statements for the temp tables since each product has different values

Comment: @MatthewJakachira, i just created a stand-alone demo, so i declared table variables (with short names  because i don't know exact names of your Order Table and Pricing table; change those names to what you need)

Comment: I will need to double check my data but I think that will work great thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I haven't done a thorough check on this SQL, but I'm pretty sure you can accomplish the task using something along the lines of this:

```
WITH OrdersPricing AS (
    SELECT
        ot.OrderId,
        (SELECT TOP(1) pt.PriceId
        FROM PriceTable pt
        WHERE pt.Qty > ot.Qty
        ORDER BY pt.Qty DESC) AS PriceId)
    FROM
        OrdersTable ot
)
SELECT
    op.PriceId,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    OrdersPricing op
GROUP BY
    op.PriceId
```